# How can I gain more uses of a specific natural attack (or pair of natural attacks) in a turn?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, dnd-3e, attack, natural-weapon

I'm building around using the 3.5 Eldritch Claws* feat for my Warlock, which count as a pair of natural attacks added to the damage your Unarmed Attack deals.  I would like to gain more attacks with these, how can I go about doing this?  Thus far I know of spending 3 feats and getting only a single additional attack (Improved Unarmed Strike, Feral Combat Training, and Snap Kick), and I'm likely to take that since it seems like I'll have feats to spare, but it's still a steep cost for just one extra attack.

The game I'll be using this build in is a heavily houseruled Pathfinder game by the way, which allows all official content from 3.0/3.5/PF as well as Dreamscarred Press material.  Other 3rd party and homebrew material may be approved on a case by case basis.

*Eldritch Claws is a feat found in Dragon #358 pg87

Comment: I'm thinking you need more limbs.

Comment: That was what one person suggested. And I may go that route.  The problem is that by RAW Eldritch Claws specifically states 2 claw attacks so it might be ruled against (unlikely, but still might happen).

Comment: Ah, I assume you're referring to this Eldritch Claws (http://www.realmshelps.net/cgi-bin/featbox.pl?feat=Eldritch_Claws), rather than this one (http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/eldritch-claws), then? That makes sense, but I was initially misled. Perhaps a link in the question is in order. (Or maybe I'm the only one who was confused.)

Comment: Aah...  I don't think I should link to the realmshelps one due to the fact that I don't know if Dragon Magazine material is fair game to post online like that but yeah I'll mention that's the one I'm referring to.

Comment: You gotta supply *some* limits. With *infinite* cash, feats, time, minions, and the like, situations can be contrived to get you infinite attacks. Is the plan to stay warlock? What are your other feats? What's the highest level you expect your character to reach?

Comment: The problem is I'm trying to get additional natural attacks with a specific weapon, a pre-existing natural weapon.  In this instance, Eldritch Claws.  Not additional attacks in general, because that's just a silly amount of possibilities.

Answer (score 5):

## Rapidstrike and Improved Rapidstrike give claws pseudo-iteratives

The Rapidstrike and Improved Rapidstrike feats from *Draconomicon* allow claws to be used more often in a single full-attack. In addition to high BAB requirements (+10 and +15 respectively), they require that you be one of the following types:

- aberration
- dragon
- elemental
- magical beast
- plant

There are LA +0 options for aberration ([elan](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/psionicRaces.htm#elans)) and dragon (dragonborn, dragonwrought kobold, spellscale; all *Races of the Dragon*), but I don’t believe there are for elemental, magical beast, or plant. There are numerous ways to obtain these types after the fact, but most are very expensive.

## Beast Strike allows you to add claw damage to unarmed strikes

Beast Strike from *Dragon* vol. 355 allows you to add the damage of a claw attack to an unarmed strike attack. This is otherwise a normal unarmed strike, i.e. you can use it for whatever attacks you like, you can Flurry with it, and so on.

Because Eldritch Claws base their damage on your unarmed strike damage, and then you add the Eldritch Claws’ damage on to your unarmed strikes, you effectively *double* your unarmed strike damage when you do this. And because it’s not *really* doubling (just adding the same thing twice), it is multiplied, e.g. on critical hits, rather than 3.5’s usual multiplier-addition.

But also note that Beast Strike is a rather poorly-written feat that causes a fair amount of confusion. We have a couple of questions on it as it is:

- [Does Beast Strike add Strength to damage twice?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/26656/4563)
- [How does Beast Strike interact with a monk with natural attacks?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/26659/4563)

The answers to both questions is *we can’t say for sure* because Beast Strike is a rather confusing feat. That said, confusing though it is, it’s a **good** feat, and I don’t mean that it’s super-powerful. It’s a reasonable buff to a certain niche build, and I think it improves the game for it to exist, even if you do have to houserule a few things in because the feat is vague.

Comment: I didn't know about the draconomicon feats, though someone did mention Beast Strike in a chat I was in (though in regards to an unrelated situation, and I noticed its possible application to this).  Having more information in this case does help so I know what I'm getting into by getting that feat though.

Comment: The DM may allow bypassing the weirdly restrictive  prerequisites of the feat Rapidstrike *et al.* without changing type by employing an a feat-granting magic item (*Arms and Equipment Guide* 128).

Answer (score 1):

[Action points](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/adventuring/actionPoints.htm) (also seen in Eberron) let you do this, albeit at only once per round unless you can convince your GM to remove that restriction.

Answer (score 0):

I can only answer with regards to Pathfinder.  The [Speed](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/speed) weapon ability will grant you an extra attack.  This will require a +3 Amulet of Mighty Fists.  Also, while not entirely applicable to you, if you somehow become an animal companion and don't enough natural attacks for its modified Multiattack, you gain an iterative attack with your natural attack.  Since you're playing a heavily modified version of Pathfinder, it wouldn't be unreasonable to work that the actual Multiattack feat works just as the one on the Animal Companion chart.